# Qt Custom Widget Size

Tags: c++, qt, widget, size

I am writing a custom widget with qt. I was wondering if there was a way that I could hard code the width of the widget so it will always remain that size?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
widget->SetFixedWidth(myWidth);
widget->SetFixedHeight(myHeight);
widget->SetFixedSize(mySize);
```